# MySQL cross product excluding symmetric results

Tags: mysql, join

I want to take the cross product of a table with itself but I only want asymmetric results.

For example, suppose I have these subject codes:

```
CH10001
CS21003
MA10001
```

The cross product with condition "not equal" will result in 6 rows:

```
CH10001,CS21003
CH10001,MA10001
CS21003,MA10001
CS21003,CH10001
MA10001,CH10001
MA10001,CS21003
```

But I want only 3 rows in the output. That is:

```
(CH10001,CS21003) OR (CS21003,CH10001)
(CH10001,MA10001) OR (MA10001,CH10001)
(CS21003,MA10001) OR (MA10001,CS21003)
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Are you expecting a result of 3 rows with 3 columns?

Comment: 3 rows two columns each each column with one course code

Comment: either (CH10001,CS21003) or (CS21003,CH10001) in a row

Comment: So you want a cross join with duplicate pairs (A,B)(B,A) removed?

Comment: I want either (A,B) or (B,A) in my row not both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    case when a.courseID <= b.courseID 
      then a.courseID 
      else b.courseID 
     end id1,
    case when a.courseID <= b.courseID 
      then b.courseID 
      else a.courseID 
    end id2
  from course A cross join course B
HAVING id1 <> id2
```

Returns the first result

```
[CH10001    CS21003]
[CH10001    MA10001]
[CS21003    MA10001]
```

[Here's the SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66ef64/29)

Comment: was able to do this by following query using your less than Idea

"select l.courseCode,r.courseCode from subject as l,subject as r where l.courseCode < r.courseCode"

Thanks for the help